# style.display not working on appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

could anybody explain, why this code not work?

in my js file I have:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
var backOverlay = document.createElement('div');
    backOverlay.id = "BackOverlay";
    backOverlay.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.7;z-index:100;background:#000;top:0;left:0;display:block';
    document.body.appendChild(backOverlay);
    if (backOverlay){
        backOverlay.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
    }   
    });//on dom load
    toggle = function(){   
           var el = document.getElementById("BackOverlay");       
            if (el.style.display == "block"){
                el.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                el.style.display = "block";                       
            }              
        }//toggle
```

this code creates div-element, but on click div only change transparency(sic!!!)

But if I create div on page, not in js - everything fine

```
<body>
/////page elements here///
<div id="BackOverlay" onclick="toggle();" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.7;z-index:100;background:#000;top:0;left:0;display:block"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by defining the function first

```
toggle = function(){   
   var el = document.getElementById("BackOverlay");       
    if (el.style.display == "block"){
        el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        el.style.display = "block";                       
    }              
}


 var backOverlay = document.createElement('div');
 backOverlay.id = "BackOverlay";
 backOverlay.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.7;z-index:100;background:#000;top:0;left:0;display:block';
 document.body.appendChild(backOverlay);
 if (backOverlay){
   backOverlay.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
 }
```

Comment: I see it working on jsfiddle. But on localhost is not
May be i need to specify:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
//here I create backOverlay element
}

may be here is problem?

Comment: then there may be some other issue? any error in console?

Comment: I edit the post, addfull code with onDomContentLoad
in console all ok: previous/current display style lod none/block or block/none on click.

Comment: Its working fine man. Created a html file with your code only

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked in both the conditions?
What is your exact question?

```js
var backOverlay = document.createElement('div');
backOverlay.id = "BackOverlay";
backOverlay.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.7;z-index:100;background:#000;top:0;left:0;display:block';
document.body.appendChild(backOverlay);
if (backOverlay){
    backOverlay.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
}   

function toggle(){   
  alert("called");
       var el = document.getElementById("BackOverlay");       
        if (el.style.display == "block"){
            el.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            el.style.display = "block";                       
        }              
    }//toggle
```

Comment: Its working fine on jsfiddle. On localhost this code only change transparency (??) of div. any console.log output correct value of display property: none/block. But the div is still on the screen

Comment: question is still not clear. What are you trying to achieve.